# Перегрузка операторов ввода и вывода C++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Пытаюсь реализовать перегрузку операторов ввода и вывода в поток для класса. Код следующий:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MYSTRING_H
#define MYSTRING_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/*Namespace for a MyString class*/
namespace str {

    /*MyString class*/
    class MyString {

        char* string = nullptr;
        size_t* size = nullptr;

    public:

        MyString();
        MyString(char* const new_string);
        MyString(const MyString& input_string);
        MyString(const size_t& size, const char& symbol);

        ~MyString();

        size_t length() const;

        char* c_str() const;

        char& operator[](const int& n);

        char* operator=(char* const input_string);

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const MyString& output_string);

        friend istream& operator>>(istream& stream, MyString& input_string);
    };


    ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const MyString& output_string) {
        stream << output_string.string;
        return stream;
    }

    istream& operator>>(istream& stream, MyString& input_string) {
        char* input_data = nullptr;
        int counter = 0;
        char symbol;
        while (true) {
            if ((symbol = stream.get()) != '\n') {
                input_data = (char*)realloc(input_data, ++counter);
                input_data[counter - 1] = symbol;
            }
            else {
                input_data = (char*)realloc(input_data, ++counter);
                input_data[counter - 1] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        input_string.string = new char[counter];
        strcpy_s(input_string.string, counter, input_data);
        *input_string.size = input_string.length();
        return stream;
    }
}
#endif // MYSTRING_H
```

Делаю как в [этом](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx) примере. Получаю ошибку:

> fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Реализация остальных методов - в отдельном файле cpp. Проблема именно с операторами ввода и вывода.

Что я делаю не так? VS17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что включаете этот h-файл (содержащий не-inline *определения* операторов) в несколько .cpp-файлов. тем самым нарушая *правило одного определения*...

Comment: Все верно, большое спасибо!

Comment: Ну, тогда помечайте ответ как принятый.

Comment: Слишком быстро ответили, через 5 минут обязательно отмечу